# Use different translations for same ActiveModel class in different contexts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I know it is a slight anti-pattern to do this, nevertheless sometimes it just would be a much easier solution than implementing different logic classes or fully-functional decorators/form-objects for just a tiny bit of difference.

Given i have a User class (ActiveModel), and i want to use this in more than one different context, say SignUp and Login.
For SignUp i want to be able to have different translations than for the Login, for example be able to provide a different message for a invalid email-format.

Is there any simple way to accomplis this? While being able to work on the same class of object. So SignUp and Login should both operate on the FULL User class allowing to use the logic provided in it.

Ideally as simple as taking the instance and setting a variable on the instance to change the 'model_name' part of the i18n-tree.

I tried several ways:

#### Delegation

```
class Login < DelegateClass(User)
end
```

Perfect for simply overwriting/adding logic at instance level. Unfortunately all the Rails i18n stuff operates on class level and there is no way to get this in, since `self` reflects user and not login and there is no real Login-class to attach logic too.

#### Decoration

Would be the ideal solution in a perfect world, like using form-objects (reform etc) but its impossible to use the User logic (like validations) without some pain in the ass, duplicating or even re-implementing them in more complicated cases (like checking email uniqueness etc). Too much overhead for just a simple translation-text change.
Plus this often comes with its full set of own translations etc, and i don't want to duplicate all that unless really needed - maybe just change a few of the default ones.

#### Inheritance

For only the initial case (allowing to change translations for validations) perfect:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  ...
  class User < ::User
  end
end
```

This little piece of magic adds another layer to the front of the I18n fallbacks, so there is suddenly a 'login_controller/user' that is looked up before 'user' in the tree.
Unfortunately you make any additional operations on the object with a different class, so you have to be very careful when doing this, which will have some unintended side-effects.

Are there any better solutions out there? As i said, i know the perfect one would be to not even operate on the ActiveModel object directly, but sometimes it's just complete overkill to introduce business logic objects to handle everything - and duplicate tons of logic again and again.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle translations is using the built in I18n library.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

This way you can set a key of `:sign_in_text` or `:email_format_error` and have it be replaced dynamically depending on the locale that is chosen.

And you would use it similarly to below, with a few additional setup details in the link about it above.

```
# config/locales.en.yml
en:
  home:
    index:
      sign_in_header: "Sign Up Here!"
```

and in the view

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<h1><%= t :sign_in_header %></h1>
```

Comment: That works nicely for view-level translations, but not for anything that comes from the models, like model/attribute-names or validation error messages. Sure i could re-define messages like "email_format_error" in the scope of the login-view but then i would need to add a ton of logic to the view when to display each message.

Comment: Errors should be converted correctly based on the locale set.  see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#overview-of-other-built-in-methods-that-provide-i18n-support .  There is also some info around overriding the defaults that would come out of those messages too

Comment: This only works for ONE case of translations, but i want to be able to use different sets or even inheritance of translations per case. I do know deeply how rails i18n works but i found no satisfying way of solving this additional requirement.